# Way + (complete sentence / incomplete sentence)

Tags: word-usage

way + complete sentence

> 1. I make a decision in the way I think I should make a decision, not in the way others think I should.

way + incomplete sentence.

> 2 .I make a decision in the way that I think is right.

Here, ***the way*** is a subject of ***right***.

So, I'd like to know if I can use both of them: way + complete / incomplete

Comment: I don't know why you would say **the way** is a subject of **right**.  i would say that "right" is a _subject complement_ in the form of a _predicate adjective_.  "Way" is the subject of the phrase "way that I think is right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these relatives are equally "complete"; the difference is that your first omits the *relativizer*—*that* or *which*.

A relativizer is a word which points backward towards a constituent of the main clause, the *referent* and forward toward a *gap*—a missing constituent—in the relative clause. It tells your hearer that the gap may be "filled in" with the referent, just like a fill-in-the-blank exercise or test.

Here are the unrelativized forms, with __ representing the gap:

1. I think I should make a decision _ ...*the gap represents an adverbial, something like* "in this way"
2. I think _ is right ... *the gap represents a nominal, something like* "this way"

Note that both are "incomplete" in exactly the same way: there's a missing piece. Except for that, they're both full clauses—both "complete".

We have a main clause "I make a decision in the way ..." where we want to add 1 or 2 to define that *way*. To link 1 or 2 we use a relativizer after the term to be defined—the referent—and . I'll use *that* for the relativizer, because you do in your #2; but *which* works equally well:

1. I make a decision in the way **that** *I think I should make a decision _*.
2. I make a decision in the way **that** *I think _ is right*.

Note that #2 here is exactly like your #2, while #1 has a *that* which is not present in your #1. However, the relativizer is only **required** if the missing piece—the gap—is the subject of the relative clause; it may be omitted in both of these sentences:

1. I make a decision in the way *I think I should make a decision _*.
2. I make a decision in the way *I think _ is right*.

Of course when you speak or write these there is no "_", no explicit gap, just an 'absence'. It is this absence that your hearer looks for to interpret what you have said.